# How to get accurate time information from ffmpeg audio outputs?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I want to figure out the best way to have accurate (down to millisecond) time information encoded into a web stream audio recording. So, if I wanted to know what was streaming at exactly 07:57:25 yesterday, I could retrieve that information using my program code. How can I do this in my ffmpeg function?

So far I have a python script that calls the following ffmpeg function every hour:

```
ffmpeg -i http://webstreamurl.mp3 -t 01:30:00 outputname.mp3
```

It will record 1.5 hours of my stream every hour. This leaves me with many 1.5 hour-long clips which together (due to some overlap) will give me audio at every moment.

I don't know how I will sync these clips with their stream times, however. Is there a way to put timestamps in the audio and have python read it? Or is there a way to name these output files such that python could calculate the times itself? Any other way?

Comment: as you are using mp3 have you considered using id3 metadata to store the start time?

Comment: I am using mp3 though I am not attached to that format. How does id3 work?

Comment: its a metadata collection embedded into the files, ffmpeg can set values in them using the -metadata parameter, your program code could then read the same tag to know the start time

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into this now. I appreciate your help!